# Vector access violation, empty index, iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, shared-ptr, access-violation

I'm writing a game and I'm struggling with memory management. I've been getting some various run time errors. Here's some code:

In a level class:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Projectile> projectile_ptr;
std::vector<projectile_ptr> projectileList;
```

So we are gonna have multiple projectiles, stored in the vector (or list?). I add them to the vector like this:

```
void Level::addProjectile(projectile_ptr ptr)
{
    projectileList.push_back(ptr);
}

//somewhere else in the code
projectile_ptr projectile(new Projectile(PT_BULLET, true, &p));
game->level->addProjectile(projectile);
```

Now in other 2 places I read the list. In the Game class when I update the game status before render, and in the Renderer when projectiles are going to be drawn.

I iterate through the vector like this:

```
for (std::vector<projectile_ptr>::iterator it = game->level->projectileList.begin(); it != game->level->projectileList.end();) {
    Projectile & projectile = *(*it); 

    if (projectile.isDestroyed) {
        it = game->level->projectileList.erase(it);
        break;
    }
    projectile.calculatePosition(ticks);
    //some other calculations
    ++it;
}

for (std::vector<projectile_ptr>::iterator it = game->level->projectileList.begin(); it != game->level->projectileList.end(); ++it) {
    Projectile & projectile = *(*it);
    if (projectile.isReadyToRender) {
        //drawing code
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code above, why I'm getting strange runtimes?

[Also look on the attached screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZZc5.png)

How is it possible there is an empty space in the vector, as shared_ptr takes care of deleting objects?

I've been getting runtimes at both erasing and rendering loops. Please help.

Comment: Questions like this should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You could have bugs anywhere in your code really. For example `new Projectile(PT_BULLET, true, &p);` is suspicious and probably a bug

Comment: `SDL_Point p2 = SDL_Point{ launchPointRight->rect.x,launchPointRight->rect.y };`
`PT_BULLET` is an enum.

Comment: That is not an MCVE. Did you follow the link MM gave you? It's a link to the Help Centre that you were shown when you signed up here.

Comment: I agree totally with MM and LRO, you should post a MCVE to get complete help. Just a small note, my feeling is that here: `if (projectile.isDestroyed) {...} **else** {...}`. I think there is a *else* missing out there. Just a feeling. We cant help you more without an MCVE.

Comment: This is a SDL2 project, how u want me to present u whole example?

Comment: Set a Break Point and step into each function call line by line and keep a watch of your internal vectors to find out which line is causing your error and which iteration you are on. Make sure that you are not prematurely deleting a pointer from your container then trying to increment afterwards. This will cause your iterator to become invalid and will either throw an unhandled exception, or corruption in heap if dynamically allocated. Other than that; I can not tell where your error is for the source that you provided is limited.

Comment: The problem here is I can't so easily recreate this, I need like a minute of shooting projectiles for this to happen. Projectiles are removed after they go out of the screen so breakpoints dont help much here...

Comment: I've been also getting incompatible iterators errors...